# How to handle org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException, I using try catch but it doesn't work

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

> This method is for saving data in database

```
public Response saveAll(PurchaseOrderHeaderDto purchaseOrderHeaderDto){
    try{
        s=sf.openSession();
        tx=s.beginTransaction();
        PurchaseOrderHeader orderDo=importDao(purchaseOrderHeaderDto);
        for(int i=0;i<orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().size(); i++){
            orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().get(i).setHeaderDetails(orderDo);
            s.save(orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().get(i));
        }
        response.setStatus(200);
        response.setMessage("succesfull");
        tx.commit();

    }
    catch(ConstraintViolationException  e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        response.setStatus(500);
        response.setMessage("unsuccesfull");
        tx.rollback();

    }
    finally{
        s.close();
    }
    return response;
}
```

> `I am getting this error`

```
 Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement]
```

> I am not getting how to handle this exception(I know it is because of length but i want to handle this exception. Any suggestions are welcomed)

Answer (score 0):

cause you are trying to catch `ConstraintViolationException`  while you are getting `DataException`.
Try to use code below:

```
public Response saveAll(PurchaseOrderHeaderDto purchaseOrderHeaderDto) {
    try {
        s = sf.openSession();
        tx = s.beginTransaction();
        PurchaseOrderHeader orderDo = importDao(purchaseOrderHeaderDto);
        for (int i = 0; i < orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().size(); i++) {
            orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().get(i).setHeaderDetails(orderDo);
            s.save(orderDo.getPurchaseItemList().get(i));
        }
        response.setStatus(200);
        response.setMessage("succesfull");
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        response.setStatus(500);
        response.setMessage("unsuccesfull");
        tx.rollback();

    } finally {
        s.close();
    }
    return response;
}
```

this wil catch every exception, you may want to work on that later on, but it should work

Comment: well this will work but i want to catch the column which is causing the error...how should i do...any suggestions are welcomed

Comment: there will be no `ConstraintViolationException`  as Hibernate is just using `DataException` for that reason